# Displaying JSON object key value in HTML textfield

Tags: javascript, html

So lets say right now, I received a JSON object:

```
var myDetails = {
    RecipientName: "Jake",
    Address: "51 Lake District",
    CountryName: "United States"
}
```

and I want to display each key value on the textfields of my HTML page as below:

[image]

I managed to get it done by:

```js
var myDetails = {
    RecipientName: "Jake",
    Address: "51 Lake District",
    CountryName: "United States"
}

var output_display = [
    ["name", "RecipientName"],
    ["address", "Address"],
    ["country", "CountryName"]
];

for (i=0;i<output_display.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById(output_display[i][0]).value = myDetails[output_display[i][1]]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type = "text" id = "name" disabled>
  <label>Address of Residence</label>
  <input type = "text" id = "address" disabled>
  <label>Country of Origin</label>
  <input type = "text" id = "country" disabled>
  <script src = "test.js"></script>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
```

However, one thing I'm having second thoughts about is having to **introduce the variable "output_display"** in Javascript which is **somewhat hardcoding the HTML textfield id** with the **JSON Object key value**. Is there a more elegant and efficient way of doing this?

**Edit**

I could make the id of the textfields same as the key of the JSON but isn't it a bad practice to include uppercase in id naming?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: If you name your inputs to match the keys of the object you can simply iterate over the `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys()`

Comment: @pilchard I could rename the id to match the keys but I've read that its not a good practice to have uppercase letters for ids?

Comment: If you want to keep them lowercase you can `.toLowerCase()` the key in the `.getElementById()` call.  `Object.entries(myDetails).forEach(([key, value]) => document.getElementById(key.toLowerCase()).value = value);` and ids like `id="recipientname"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get all keys as an array.

```js
var myDetails = {
    RecipientName: "Jake",
    Address: "51 Lake District",
    CountryName: "United States"
}
const keys = Object.keys(myDetails);
```

`keys` will be `['RecipientName', 'Address', 'CountryName']`.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip using the `output_display`.

just use the object keys as ids this code will be cleaner

```js
var myDetails = {
    RecipientName: "Jake",
    Address: "51 Lake District",
    CountryName: "United States"
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(myDetails)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
   document.getElementById(key).value = value
}
```

```html
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="RecipientName" disabled><br>
  <label>Address of Residence</label>
  <input type="text" id="Address" disabled><br>
  <label>Country of Origin</label>
  <input type="text" id="CountryName" disabled><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write these instead of for loop.

```
document.getElementById('name').value=myDetails.RecipientName
document.getElementById('adress').value=myDetails.Address
document.getElementById('country').value=myDetails.CountryName
```